# Use of location settings in wp7.1

Tags: geolocation, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

What is the use of locationsettings on windowsphone 7.1. emulator
It had the option to switch on/off the location in windowsphone7.1 emulator
(Settings/Application/InternetExplorer). I used the location settings in my app, but the settings could not work.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator will also emulate location information.  If you look on the toolstrip (to the top-right of the emulator window - yes, the one with the close button on it) and click on the " » " icon, you will see the additional tools window.  The 2nd tab in that window is the Location emulator, and from here you can set up the location(s) that get reported to the main emulator for use in your application.

For more information, see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202933%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I am not asking about the additional tools. I want to know, how to detect the location settings through code. wp7.5 emulator had the options to turn "off/on" the current locations on the emulator - settings/Application(Menu)/InternetExplorer.